# How can we display first row and last row of given table using rownum without using union clause

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

**Sample Input**

```
Name | Value | Timestamp
-----|-------|-----------------
One  | 1     | 2016-01-01 02:00
Two  | 3     | 2016-01-01 03:00
One  | 2     | 2016-01-02 02:00
Two  | 4     | 2016-01-03 04:00
```

**Desired Output**

| Name | Value | EarliestTimestamp | LatestTimestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 2 | 2016-01-01 02:00 | 2016-01-02 02:00 |
| Two | 4 | 2016-01-01 03:00 | 2016-01-03 04:00 |

**Instead of using union clause to display the first and last row. How can we display it?**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE ROWNUM IN (SELECT MAX(ROWNUM) FROM TABLE);
```

Please let me the solution for this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not  clear what do you want really, "desired output" or the output of your `UNION ALL` ? They are different

Comment: @Serg - that should be pretty obvious (since the `union all` query will generally produce only one row; the second query produces nothing if the table has >= 2 rows, and it will repeat the single row of the table if the table has exactly one row).

Comment: Do you want the results separately for each Name? Or just two rows for the entire table (regardless of "names")?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be describing aggregation:

```
select name, max(value), min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from t
group by name;
```

Your question suggests that you might want the latest value instead of the maximum.  If so, use the `first` aggregate function:

```
select name,
       max(value) keep (dense_rank first order by timestamp desc),
       min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from t
group by name;
```

Documentation for `first`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/FIRST.html#GUID-85AB9246-0E0A-44A1-A7E6-4E57502E9238

Comment: The technical name of the compound aggregate `max(...) keep (dense_rank first/last....)` is not **keep**. Rather, it's the **first / last** aggregate function. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/FIRST.html#GUID-85AB9246-0E0A-44A1-A7E6-4E57502E9238

Comment: Also, just curious - why the `first` aggregate function, with timestamps ordered `desc`, and not simply the `last` function?